why does this code prints " " instead of "." however it prints the other elements correctly?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0) , cin.tie(NULL) , cout.tie(NULL) ;

    int n , m , t ; cin >> n >> m >> t ;

    char arr[n][m] = {'.'} ;                           
                                                       
    while ( t-- ) {                                    
                                                      
        int r1 , r2 , c1 , c2 ; char ch ;             
        cin >> r1 >> r2 >> c1 >> c2 >> ch ;           

        r1-- ; r2-- ; c1-- ; c2-- ;  
        for ( int i = r1 ; i <= c1 ; i++ ) { 
            for ( int j = r2 ; j <= c2 ; j++ ) { 
                arr[i][j] = ch ; 
            }
        }
    }
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
        for ( int  j = 0 ; j < m ; j++ ) {
            cout << arr[i][j] ;
        }
        cout << endl ;
    }
}


The first line of input contains 3 integers n , m , and t .
Followed by t lines each contains 4 integers r1,r2,c1,c2 , and a lowercase Latin letter ch .
I have to fill the sub-grid between rows r1 and r2 and columns c1 and c2 , with the letter ch .
And the rest of array elements is . .
testcase :
input:
6 6 3
1 1 2 6 a
5 1 6 6 c
2 3 5 4 b

output found:
aaaaaa
aabbaa
  bb
  bb
ccbbcc
cccccc

output expected:
aaaaaa
aabbaa
..bb..
..bb..
ccbbcc
cccccc



char arr[n][m] = {'.'} ; - variable-length arrays are not part of standard C++. Use std::vector instead. But even so, you are initializing only the 1st element with '.', all of the other elements are initialized with '\0' instead. Use std::fill() or std::fill_n() to set all of the elements to the same value.

char arr[n][m] = {'.'} ; is a non-standard VLA which is not part of the c++ language. With that said it tells the compiler to initialize arr[0][0] to '.' and the rest of the elements in arr to 0.

... and even if VLAs were a part of standard C++, initializing VLAs isn't legal (in standard C where the extension is borrowed from).

@RemyLebeau so even if I fill in the other elements using a loop it will not work?

so even if I fill in the other elements using a loop it will not work?  Correct, it won't work on standard C++.  If you are using a non-standard C++, then I don't know since I don't use non-standard C++.

@RemyLebeau Why std::vector instead of std::array, since the size is known?

@Razan Did you really try char arr[n][m]; std::memset(arr, '.', sizeof arr); ?

@Barmar I think the point is that the sizes are not known at compile time so standard C++ doesn't have a suitable array type handy.

@TedLyngmo I dont know about this function yet

@TedLyngmo I mistakenly thought std::array could take a runtime size.

@Razan It fills the whole arr memory with . and you only filled element [0][0] with ..

char arr[n][m] = {'.'} ;

doesn't initialize arr to all dots. It initializes it to have a dot in element [0][0], and zeroes (the null character) in all other elements.
If you want to use a plain char[][] array (which isn't a great idea in C++, but let's just suppose for the moment), and you want to fill it with all dots, write a loop that does so instead of using an initializer.

That doesn't explain why they're getting spaces.

@Barmar nulls look like spaces on the terminal, usually.

No they don't. They look like nothing, it shouldn't move the cursor to the right at all.

Also, memset could be used to initialize the array without doing the loop manually.


char arr[n][m] = {'.'} ;

You are initializing only the 1st array element with '.', all of the other array elements are initialized with '\0' instead.
But even so, variable-length arrays are not part of standard C++.
You can use a 2D std::vector instead, eg:
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<char>> arr(n, std::vector<char>(m, '.'));

Or:
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<char>> arr(n);
for(auto &elem: arr) {
    elem.resize(m, '.');
}

Online Demo
Or, use a 1D vector instead and calculate its indexes, eg:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0) , cin.tie(NULL) , cout.tie(NULL) ;

    int n , m , t ; cin >> n >> m >> t ;

    vector<char> arr(n*m, '.');
                                                       
    while ( t-- ) {                                    
                                                      
        int r1 , r2 , c1 , c2 ; char ch ;             
        cin >> r1 >> r2 >> c1 >> c2 >> ch ;           

        r1-- ; r2-- ; c1-- ; c2-- ;  
        for ( int i = r1 ; i <= c1 ; i++ ) { 
            for ( int j = r2 ; j <= c2 ; j++ ) { 
                arr[(i*n)+j] = ch ; 
            }
        }
    }
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
        for ( int  j = 0 ; j < m ; j++ ) {
            cout << arr[(i*n)+j] ;
        }
        cout << endl ;
    }
}

Online Demo
In which case, you could just use a std::string instead:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0) , cin.tie(NULL) , cout.tie(NULL) ;

    int n , m , t ; cin >> n >> m >> t ;

    string str(n*m, '.');
                                                       
    while ( t-- ) {                                    
                                                      
        int r1 , r2 , c1 , c2 ; char ch ;             
        cin >> r1 >> r2 >> c1 >> c2 >> ch ;           

        r1-- ; r2-- ; c1-- ; c2-- ;  
        for ( int i = r1 ; i <= c1 ; i++ ) { 
            for ( int j = r2 ; j <= c2 ; j++ ) { 
                str[(i*n)+j] = ch ; 
            }
        }
    }
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
        for ( int  j = 0 ; j < m ; j++ ) {
            cout << str[(i*n)+j] ;
        }
        cout << endl ;
    }
}

Online Demo
